# Comparing a weak fluent API with a strong fluent API in Java

Tags: java, comparative-review, fluent-interface

I have this simple POJO:

```
package com.github.coderodde.person;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Person {

    private int age;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public Person() {
        
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        
        if (this.age != other.age) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (!Objects.equals(this.firstName, other.firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return Objects.equals(this.lastName, other.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person[age = " 
                + age 
                + ", firstName = \'" 
                + firstName 
                + "\', lastName = \'" 
                + lastName 
                + "\']";
    }
    
    public static LastNameSelector withFirstName(String firstName) {
        return new LastNameSelector(firstName);
    }
    
    public static final class LastNameSelector {
        
        private final String firstName;
        
        LastNameSelector(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        
        public AgeSelector withLastName(String lastName) {
            return new AgeSelector(firstName, lastName);
        }
    }
    
    public static final class AgeSelector {
        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;
        
        AgeSelector(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        
        public Person withAge(int age) {
            return new Person(firstName, lastName, age);
        }
    }
}
```

The above implementation defines, what I call, a **strong** fluent API, that enforces the order of setters.

On the other hand, I have a weak fluent API, in which the order of setters is arbitrary:

```
package com.github.coderodde.person;

public class PersonBuilder {
    
    private Person person;
    
    public static PersonBuilder newPerson() {
        PersonBuilder personBuilder = new PersonBuilder();
        personBuilder.person = new Person();
        return personBuilder;
    }
    
    public PersonBuilder withAge(int age) {
        person.setAge(age);
        return this;
    }
    
    public PersonBuilder withFirstName(String firstName) {
        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        return this;
    }
    
    public PersonBuilder withLastName(String lastName) {
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        return this;
    }
    
    public Person create() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

(The demo code follows.)

```
package com.github.coderodde.person;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person alice =
                PersonBuilder
                        .newPerson()
                        .withLastName("Funky II")
                        .withAge(34)
                        .withFirstName("Alice")
                        .create();
        
        System.out.println(alice);
        
        Person bob = Person.withFirstName("Bob")
                           .withLastName("Davidson")
                           .withAge(36);
        
        System.out.println(bob);
    }
}
```

Now, my question is: which one should I use in industrial code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered yourself. Use the second one when the order matters, although I can't think of a situation when I ever needed that. I expect that in most cases the typical builder pattern will be just fine and order isn't as important as much as ensuring all the required data to the builder have been set.

A few points:

- In your example neither of your approaches makes sense and the correct solution would be to use constructor.
- There is absolutely no validation and I see that as a big problem.
- I find this usage overall pretty cool, but when in the end you are creating just anemic domain model, it loses all it's charm.
- I would restrict empty constructor of `Person` and have identical fields in the builder rather than reference of "unfinished" `Person instance`.
- If I was to implement this myself, the first solution would internally use the second solution to hold the temporary data.